Can Atlas Search storedSource include just the "_id"?
I have a certain use case where I need to return just the "_id" field of all the documents for a query.
To improve the performance, we thought of using "storedSource" option of index configuration.

List that contains the field names or dot-separated paths to fields to store. In addition to the specified fields, Atlas Search stores _id also by default.
Reference: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/atlas-search/stored-source-definition/#options

As can be seen in the MongoDB docs —
The "include" field of "storedSource" object is a list that contains the field names or dot-separated paths to fields to store. In addition to the specified fields, Atlas Search stores _id also by default.
So if I include one field (e.g. - ["dataPoint1"]),
"storedSource": {
    "include": ["dataPoint1"]
}

Atlas Search would store this one field and "_id". I don't want to unnecessarily store "dataPoint1" for all documents in store. I imagine it would require double the memory space.
Is it possible to have just the "_id" in the stored source?

I tried configuring the storedSource "include" option as an empty array []. The index build failed.

"storedSource": {
    "include": []
}


I tried configuring the storedSource as follows. The index build was successful but exclude was ignored and removed.

"storedSource": {
    "include": ["dataPoint1"],
    "exclude": ["dataPoint1"] // ignored and removed
}


I tried configuring the storedSource as follows. The build succeeded and this works but I couldn't find any documentation to confirm this. Would this be supported in the future?

"storedSource": {
    "include": ["_id"]
}


As you mention, Atlas Search automatically include the _id field, so, you dont need to add anything into storedSource
